# While loop not continuing after starting a new thread (python)

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing

I have a server that is supposed to accept multiple clients, but for some reason when it starts a new thread for the client it doesn't continue the while loop until the client has disconnected.

In addition the while loop stops to select.select and doesn't continue until there is a pending connection for sock.accept. It also doesn't break properly and make the socket close after i change self.serverstatus value to 0

Here is the code for the server

EDIT: Fixed the line containing ct.run() to ct.start()

```
 def serverstart(self):
          self.buttonswitch("1")
          self.host = self.intip
          self.port = 5000
          s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6)
          s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
          s.bind((self.host, self.port))

          inputs = [ s ]

          s.listen(5)
          self.serverstatus = "1"
          while True:
                inputready, outputready, exceptready = select.select(inputs, [], [])
                if inputready != " " and self.serverstatus == "1":
                        c, addr = s.accept()
                        ct = threading.Thread(target=self.client_thread, args=[c, addr])
                        ct.start()
                elif self.serverstatus == "0":
                        break
          s.close()
          print "Closing socket"
          self.buttonswitch("0")

        def client_thread(self, c, addr):
          print "Connection from: " + str(addr)
          while True:
                data = c.recv(1500)
                print len(data)
                if not data:
                        break
                data = str(data).upper()
                c.send(data)
                if self.serverstatus == "0":
                        break
          c.close()
```

Comment: Why and where should `self.serverstatus` change its value? Could it also be that the while loops keeps looping and you just don't notice?

Comment: you need to call start and not run on the Thread instance.

Comment: self.serverstatus should change value when toggled from a button. I tried to print text within the while loop to see if it did indeed loop, but for some reason it got stuck to the line containing
 
"inputready, outputready, exceptready = select.select(inputs, [], [])"

Until it it got a connection. I tested it by having a print line on top and under the line and only the code on top of it got executed until an incoming connection allowed it to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ct.run()
```

I believe you need [`start`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.start) here, not [`run`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.Thread.run). A thread's `run` method is the code that will be executed when the thread starts, but calling `run` doesn't actually start the code in a separate thread.

```
ct.start()
```